# Is the power set of natural numbers equal to the union of the finite power set of natural numbers and infinite power set of natural numbers?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve an exercise which is required to prove the infinite power set of natural numbers is uncountable. To do this, I'm trying to go through the approach that $P(\mathbb{N}) = P_\infty(\mathbb{N}) \cup P_\theta(\mathbb{N})$. Where $ P_\theta(\mathbb{N})$: set of all finite subsets of $\mathbb{N}$.

Is this true or am I in delusion?

Comment: Yes, it's true. Rather obviously.

Comment: Are you asking, for $B\subseteq A$, if $A = A\cup B$ ?